# Отправка данных ajax

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? Если данные отправляю стандартными средствами, прописав атрибут action, то zayavka.php исполняется, если отправляю через ajax - ничего не происходит.
Есть форма, которую нужно проверять перед отправкой на сервер, после чего, если все все правильно, отправить данные другой странице - zayavka.php. Правильно ли я понимаю, что после отправки данных ajax'ом страница zayavka.php запустится и выполнит весь содержащийся код? Нужно ли в начале поставить условие, что если к нам пришли такие-то данные, то делаем то-то?

$(function(){

```
if (( document.anketa.vid_kredita.selectedIndex == 2) && ( document.anketa.obekt_nedvizhimosti[1].checked == true )) {
                $("#vid_kredita").css('border', 'red 1px solid');
            error=3;
            }

            if ( ( document.anketa.region.selectedIndex == 1) && ( parseInt(razm_kredita) < 600000 ) ) {
            $("#razmer_kredita").css('border', 'red 1px solid');
                        error=4;    
                    }

if(error==0){
                var data = $('#firstname').val();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/stat/zayavka.php",
                data: "data="+data,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#result").empty();
                    $("#result").append(html);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
            if(error==3)  err_text="Текст ошибки 3";
            if(error==4)  err_text="Текст ошибки 4";

            $("#messenger").html(err_text); 
            $("#messenger").fadeIn("slow"); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю у Вас подключена библиотека **jQuery**, на самом деле, через нее можно отправлять запросы на много проще.

**Пример:**

*Эту строку:*

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/stat/zayavka.php",
  data: "data="+data,
  success: function(html) {
    $("#result").empty();
    $("#result").append(html);
  }
});
```

*Заменяем на эту:*

```
$.post('/stat/zayavka.php',{peremennaya:'value'},function(data){
  if(data){
    $("#result").empty();
    $("#result").append(html);
  }
  else{
    alert('Нет ответа');
  }
});
```

**Объяснение:**

1. peremennaya - Переменная которую отправляем.
2. value - что именно отправляем.
3. data - ответ

*Пробуйте :)*

Answer (score 0):

1) zayavka.php, часом не GET ждет? - нет*.
2) ajax запрос вообще происходит? (простейший способ проверить - вставить alert('123456') перед и после 
$.ajax(); )

Comment: Нет. Там идет проверка на правильность введенных данных и дальше уже рассылка и т.д. Вот начало файла:

if(ereg("^[А-Яа-я]+$",$_POST["firstname"]) == false) $error_flag = 1;
if(ereg("^[А-Яа-я]+$",$_POST["data"]) == false) $error_flag = 1;